# Android PopUpMenu on phones integrated button

Tags: android, popupmenu

I want to create a pop menu on Android but I want it to be shown on touch of the phones hardware button, not on the screen.

But the tutorial is only on touch of some button on the screen. How do I respond to the touch of the phone's already existing buttons?

Don’t want an image button, but the integrated button in the phone.

```
<ImageButton
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_overflow_holo_dark"
   android:contentDescription="@string/descr_overflow_button"
   android:onClick="showPopup" />


public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

Comment: This is not and should not be possible.

Comment: why in the world would a user want your menu to popup every time they press a button that has nothing to do with your app??

Answer (score 0):

If I guessed your intention correctly...these are the overridden methods which invoke when you press your hardware keys...you can write you popup dialog code in these methods....

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: yes it's the right attention but i mean not the keyboard but the left button of the samsung s3 mobile phone this is in every app you can press it and the Pop Up Menu is opended with options.

Comment: ok one further question i have a listview in this activity is this the view which i have to pass to the popUp Method to show the popUp Menu but it is hidden behind the list view can anyone help. Thanks